# Excel 2010 custom text formats

Tags: text-formatting

I have a column of 9 digit numbers imported as text to avoid loss of leading zeros. I wish to apply a special format similar to SSN. When I select the new format for the column, nothing happens. How do I get the new format to display?

Comment: Can you give example of the value before import, after import, and the desired format?

Comment: Just so you know that not everyone here is from US, so giving an example of desired format similar to SSN (Social Security Number) will help people understand the desired result.

Comment: The data needs to be imported as number data, not text. Applying number formatting to text data can't work. You can add the leading zeros back in as part of your custom number formatting.

Comment: All cells contain 9 character text string composed of numerals. The specified format for display is 00-000-0000  How do I see that format applied to the cells? Is there another step needed?

Comment: Solved. Copied column and did Data>Test to Columns.